# WebSphere and Rollback message

Tags: java, java-ee-6, websphere-8

Could you please clarify the following problem. Is it possible to return message to queue in case Message Driven Bean could not process a message. My code likes :

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
           doSomethingWithMessage(message)  
         } catch (QueueListenerUtilException e) {
            LOG.error("Could not process given message try to rollback transaction");
            mdc.setRollbackOnly();
            throw e;
        }
        LOG.debug("Sending message has been started");

      this.simCntrlUtil.writeToQueue(answer, message, msgProp);
        LOG.info(" onMessage has been completed");
    }
```

I suppose that if bean throws RuntimeException the transaction will be rollbacked and after timeout will be delivered again. In server log I see message 
"Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called"

But message is not delivered again after timeout. I think that corresponded options are set in WebSphere configuration.

this

Automatically stop endpoints on repeated message failure
 Enable

Sequential failed message threshold

100

Delay between failing message retries

10000
 milliseconds

The transaction is managed by container (I did not change dedault initialization)
Could you please help me to understand : why I don't see message again?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What transaction attribute are you using? (REQUIRED or NOT_SUPPORTED) and/or are you using BMT instead of CMT?   What messaging provider are you using (WMQ or default messaging provider)?   What platform (OS) are you running WebSphere App Server on?

Comment: Also need to check the queue settings since messaging providers often support configuration to reoute the message to another queue in case of failed deliveries.

Comment: I use CMT and default messaging provider. WebSphere works on Linux Platform (Cent OS). I suppose attribute REQUIRED should be set by default? Am I right?

Comment: I've set up the  threshold for failed message, so I suppose failed message should not be immediately moved garbage queue

Comment: Also I set up delivery mode = persistent and time to live = 50000 ms

Comment: I've double checked attribute set to REQUIRED

Comment: What do you have set for *Maximum failed deliveries per message* ?